# Entity Framework returns wrong data for view with LEFT JOIN statement

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm experiencing strange behavior of Entity Framework. EF-generated `DbContext` object returns data different from the actual data in database.

Consider the following DB schema:
[image: database schema]

`Letter` data:

```
Id      Value   LanguageId
------- ------- ----------
1       A       1
2       A       2
3       B       1
4       B       2
```

`Language` data:

```
Id      Value
------- -------
1       English
2       Russian
```

I also have the following simple view `LetterLanguageView`. Note that it uses `LEFT JOIN` clause because `Letter.LanguageId` could be `NULL`:

```
SELECT dbo.Letter.Value as Letter, dbo.Language.Value as Language
FROM dbo.Letter
LEFT JOIN dbo.Language ON dbo.Letter.LanguageId = dbo.Language.Id
```

The result of this view is pretty straightforward:

```
Letter  Language
------- --------
A       English
A       Russian
B       English
B       Russian
```

However, when I use this view from Entity Framework, I have the following results:

[image: Wrong data]

As you can see, the `Language` property is wrong, there is no Russian language at all.

If you are wondering, here is the code snippet for reading this data:

```
using (var e = new TestEntities())
{
    var data = e.LetterLanguageView;
}
```

Nothing special, no conversions or any modifications of returned data, so it looks like the problem is in the Entity Framework itself.

Could you suggest any ideas why EF returns wrong data in this case and how could I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that your cardinality is setup correctly in the EF model? What is the SQL as generated by EF? (you can capture it in debug mode or with SQL profiler)

Comment: Don't use the debugger.  Actually print out the results of the query to the console or a file or something and then look at it.

Comment: @Servy, I checked the results before - this is not a debugger's bug.

Comment: @Darek, here is the EF-generated SQL code: SELECT 
[Extent1].[Letter] AS [Letter], 
[Extent1].[Language] AS [Language]
FROM (SELECT 
      [LetterLanguageView].[Letter] AS [Letter], 
      [LetterLanguageView].[Language] AS [Language]
      FROM [dbo].[LetterLanguageView] AS [LetterLanguageView]) AS [Extent1]

Comment: So this has nothing to do with the EF model @Sergey ... you have defined a VIEW in SQL and you simply retrieve it. What happens if you iterate over the collection and print out results?

Comment: What is the code for LetterLanguageView. Also when you run the EF generated SQL directly does it give the right or wrong results?

Comment: @JamesS please look for `LetterLanguageView` definition in my question above. And yes, EF-generated SQL code gives me the right results - this is really strange. So the problem is somewhere in EF mappings or something like that...

Comment: @Darek No, the problem is exactly in the EF. EF-generated SQL code gives me the right results.

Comment: In your question, where you say "I have the following results:" I do not see any results.

Comment: Also, this seems very straightforward. Are you sure your connecting to the right DB?

Comment: @EricScherrer There is a picture below with the results. Here's a direct link to it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vgYC3.png And yes, this is the right DB. I hope this synthetic example is quite easy to reproduce it on your own.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the firewall here blocks imgur. No biggie. I recall there is some funky stuff with EF and views where you have to tell EF what the PK is otherwise you get inaccurate results. I remember this because I hate mucking around in the auto-generated model. I'm playing around with it now to see if it jogs my memory.

Comment: OK - in your model - what columns (if any) did EF decide are the primary key for your view?

Comment: @EricScherrer EF decided that only `Letter` property is Entity Key.

Comment: It could be that EF is assuming items 2 and 4 are the same entity as items 1/3 - likely because the keys have not been setup correctly. Obviously it will associate duplicate items in the dataset with the same entity and most likely it's chosen the first one and ignored any dupes - you can use a composite entity key, but you must specify the order of the keys (I'm sure the designer probably does this for you) - otherwise EF is just giving you its best guess!

Comment: @Sergey Bad idea to select Letter as your only column for EntityKey.

Comment: @Darek it was chosen automatically by the EF. Looks like you should refine EF model every time you generate it!

Comment: @Sergey EF will make the best guestimate, which column should become EntityKey. Best case scenario, it finds it by looking at primary keys of the table. In your case, you are using a view (why not the tables themselves?) and as such the EntityKey will be invalid, because two groups of records, will have the same value.

Comment: @Darek Thanks for your explanation. This example is just a synthetic self-containing code to explain the problem I faced with in my real-world code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure in your EF model for LetterLanguageView that you set Letter and Language as EntityKey = true.

Another trick I have used in the past is add a row Id column and make that the PK. Here is someones (not me) blog about it

http://girlfromoutofthisworld.com/entity-framework-and-setting-primary-keys-on-views/

Comment: Thank you. Having the same problem but My headache is now in the past.