# How to get an instance of IServiceProvider in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, service-provider

`IServiceProvider` is an interface with single method:

```
object GetService(Type serviceType);
```

It's used to create instances of types registered in .NET Core native DI container.

An instance of `IServiceProvider` itself can be obtained by calling a `BuildServiceProvider` method of an `IServiceCollection`. `IServiceCollection` is a parameter of `ConfigureServices` method in a `Startup` class. It seems to be magically called with an instance of `IServiceCollection` by the framework.

I want to create an instance of `IServiceProvider` without having `Setup` method at all. I need it to resolve dependencies in an integration test assembly. Is it possible to get it at all in this scenario?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is the default implementation of `IServiceCollection` from Microsoft:
https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/DI/ServiceCollection.cs

Looking at the code then you should be able to get an `IServiceCollection` simply by calling:

```
var serviceCollection = new Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection();
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I don't see how that's useful. The new ServiceCollection is empty and won't contain any of the service registrations that would be created by `Startup.ConfigureServices` so the ServiceProvider built from it won't be capable of providing anything at all.

Comment: Quite useful actually @Neutrino - I built some extensions for configuration and need to test them

Answer (score 86):

As **goaty** mentioned it's enough to create new `ServiceCollection`. Here's example class which can be used to access DI container in .NET Core:

```
public static class ServiceProviderFactory
{
    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; }

    static ServiceProviderFactory()
    {
        HostingEnvironment env = new HostingEnvironment();
        env.ContentRootPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        env.EnvironmentName = "Development";

        Startup startup = new Startup(env);
        ServiceCollection sc = new ServiceCollection();
        startup.ConfigureServices(sc);
        ServiceProvider = sc.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

`Startup` class is taken from tested project so the service registrations don't need to be repeated.

Then in test class simply use:

```
var foo = ServiceProviderFactory.ServiceProvider.GetServices(typeof(IFoo));
```

Comment: Great answer for showing you have to activate the ServiceCollection, build the provider, and then explicitly capture the reference to it.

Comment: It seems a bit annoying to me that I have to pass an IServiceProvider around. Microsoft should have at least made a static/singleton IServiceProvider.

Comment: @Gerry Microsoft didn't do that, because passing an instanced object around is backwards compatible with singletons -- but not the other way around. Additionally, many people misuse/abuse singletons, and its not good to encourage the use of something people abuse.  If you want a static singleton service for your app, you can easily create your own singleton to encapsulate the IServiceProvider and then access it wherever you want via your own singleton. That's the backwards-compatibility part.

Comment: I don't think this is useful either. Here a new `Startup` instance is used to configure the `ServiceCollection` but this will contain different instances of any singletons used by the application, so again this does not provide access to a `ServiceProvider` that enables you to access the services configured for an application.

Comment: @Neutrino I think what you want to do is NOT quite what the OP here wants to do. But... if you want to instantiate a running instance of your app and then test it while also having access to the running app's service provider, then look into `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`. Or if you want to manually resolve a class of a given type within the app, but using explicit code to ask for the object rather than relying on the constructor injection chain, then look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32461714/795690 .

Comment: This doesn't even compile in .NET Core? `cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.HostingEnvironment' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration'`

Comment: This is not a good approach for simple reason. As you build your own ServiceProvider, you no longer can ensure the registred singletons will be still singletons as there will be two service providers each providing their instances of singletons.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ASP0000

Answer (score 25):

To get access to existing DI of ASP.NET Core application e.g. in some controller, you should just resolve it in a constructor. Example with some manager and workers:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvc();

   services.AddSingleton<IFooManager, FooManager>();
   services.AddTransient<IFooWorker, FooWorker>();
}
```

Manually resolve workers for manager:

```
public class FooManager: IFooManager
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public FooManager(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var w1 = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFooWorker>();  // new instance of FooWorker
        var w2 = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFooWorker>();  // new instance of FooWorker
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

First you need to install the [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection) NuGet package. ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0), [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection), [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.extensions.servicecollectiondescriptorextensions))

Then you create a new [`ServiceCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollection) and method chain it with the [`BuildServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectioncontainerbuilderextensions.buildserviceprovider) method. In between that you can also register any service providers.

```cs
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddSingleton<IFooService, FooService>()
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an updated approach:

```cs
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
{
    builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
        env.ContentRootPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        env.EnvironmentName = "Development";
    });

    builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
}).Build();
```

Example usage:

```cs
host.Services.GetService<IFoo>();
```

Answer (score 4):

use this
`ServiceProviderA = new ServiceCollection(). . . . . .BuildServiceProvider() .GetRequiredService<IServiceProvider>();`
this ServiceProviderA contain itself

Answer (score 3):

You can find it in Program.cs

```
public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IHost build = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
    ServiceProvider = build.Services;
    build.Run();
}
```

Comment: You can do that. BUT, you should be really aware to NEVER use this ServiceProvider directly ... maybe only for singletons ... ALWAYS create a service scope from it. Without using a scope you'll be creating a memory leak, scoped and transient services will never be disposed as ServiceProvider keeps them in a dictionary.

Comment: follow up ... Internally ServiceProvider / ServiceProviderEngine / ServiceProviderEngineScope keeps object derived from IDisposable and IAsyncDisposable in a dictionary.