# How to pass parameters besides injected services in constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor-webassembly

In constructor of the `Game` class, I am passing scoped service `ISessionsRepository` as an injected service and other parameters.

```
public class Game 
{
    private ISessionsRepository repo;

    public Game(ISessionsRepository injectedRepo, string sessionID, string sessionName) 
    {
        // *code*
    }
}
```

I know, this won't work. But I still have to create instance of `Game` class by using `new()`. And in the ctor arguments I do not want to pass `ISessionsRepository`, only `sessionID` and `sessionName`:

```
Game game = new("1", "name");
```

Comment: How does the `Game` object get created?  What calls `new()`.  You can use a pattern similar to `IOptions<>`, but then you are 1 step back, how does the correct confguration get created.

Comment: @Neil Game instance created in ISessionsRepository in CreateSession() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new constructor for Game

```
public Game(string sessionId, string sessionName) {other code}
```

EDIT:
It looks like my suggestion is an anti-pattern as stated in the first comment of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32931716/11010186).

In case you still need to access the service, what you can do is to retrieve manually the service that you need from the service container, in the class that is instantiating `Game` and passing it to `Game`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221895/how-to-get-an-instance-of-iserviceprovider-in-net-core) a question that should help you do that.

If you really don't want to pass it from the outside, you can create the new constructor that I suggested and make it request the Service you need.

Comment: But will ISessionsRepository still be injected?